# Getting the last 6 orders of all companies 

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  2 tables.. a client table..and orders table..i'm trying to get the last 6 orders from each clien, but for all the clients together...i'm having trouble thinking of how to do this haha..it's friday...any help/ideas? ..i'm using microsoft sql server studio if ya need to know

here is the code i have right now

```
select /*top 6*/ c.Company_name, oh.qms_control_nbr, c.reminder_notice 
from orderheader oh inner join clients c on oh.prnt_id = c.id
where c.status = 'Active'
group by c.company_name, oh.date_ordered, oh.qms_control_nbr, c.reminder_notice
order by c.company_name asc, c.reminder_notice asc, oh.Date_ordered desc
```

this give me all the orders for each client, ..just want to limit to last 6

so..it might give results like this

```
_company_____              __order-num___
company a                     1111
company a                     1112
company a                     1113
company a                     1114
company a                     1115
company a                     1116
company b                     1221
company b                     1222
company b                     1433
company b                     1524
company b                     1345
company b                     1436
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you have tried?  You might be close and a few suggestions might push you in the right direction.  Plus post some data sample and your expected results.

Comment: It would be useful to us if you answer this question for us: What have you tried? What is your database structure? What data do you have? What do you expect?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't been told yet: This isn't a "here's my specifications, now do my job for me" site

Comment: @Bohemian i'm not asking for you to do my job, i'm asking for a little nudge in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) OLAP Function to get this:

*Edit based on new info in question.*  I think this should get what you're looking for:

```
SELECT c.Company_name, oh.qms_control_nbr, c.reminder_notice 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prnt_id ORDER BY date_ordered DESC) AS RN
      FROM orderheader t) oh
JOIN clients c
  ON oh.prnt_id = c.id
WHERE c.status = 'Active'
  AND oh.rn < 7
ORDER BY c.company_name asc, c.reminder_notice asc, oh.Date_ordered desc
```

Comment: i changed the one line to this "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prnt_id ORDER BY date_ordered DESC) AS RN"  i think that's right..i get results..but not exactly what i'm looking for...for one comapny..i got like 11 results...it doesnt seem to be stopped at 6

Comment: lol..also changed you > to a < ...and i think that worked haha..still checking

Comment: this looks right..so i'm going to make edit it to make the changes..and pick you as the winner, still got some work for all the information, but this definitely put me in right direction..thanks

Comment: Cool!  I forgot to change some of the field names after you made your edit, so sorry about that.  Glad it's working now, though!

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 6 o.* from clienttable c
inner join orderstable o on c.columname = o.columnname
order by o.OrderProcessDate desc
```

replace `columnname` and `OrderProcessDate` by the correct columns.

Comment: this only gives me the top 6 in that order, like 1 company..i need the top 6 of each company but for all the companies...thats basically right..but it needs to automatically continue on to the next company and repeat..that is the problem i'm having